# Practice with Loops in C Programming

Tags: c

This IS a homework question, however I am only asking for debugging help. I'm not sure what is causing these errors for me.

```
int CalculateResult(int High, int Low)
{
  int Result;
  int count = 0;
  int check;
do
    {
    printf("Enter the value to check within the range: ");
    scanf("%d",&Result);

     if (Result == 0)
     {
     printf("Error! Positive value only!\n");
     }

     else if (Result < -1)
     {
     printf("Error! Positive value only!\n");
     }

     else if (Result>= 1);
     {
     for (check = Low ; check <= High;check++)
         {
         if (check%Result==0)
            {
            (count++);
            }
         }
     } 
    while (Result != -1);
    return (count);
    }
}
```

I have two errors:174:1 ---Expected while before } token
 and then there is 174:1 ---Expected declarations at end of input

Anyone see what is wrong? Sorry that it's messy, I'm a noob.

Comment: This is not a debugging question. It is a matter of syntax errors.

Comment: Match your `{` and `}`. You'll easily see the error. Hint: there's a `do {statements} while (contition)` statement and a different `while (condition) {statements}` stamement.

Comment: which line of your code snippet corresponds to line 174?

Comment: your 2nd last `}` should be before While.

Comment: Hint: if you format your code properly it will make it much easier to find your mistakes.

Comment: Choose [one indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and follow it thoroughly -- but, please, do not choose GNU style!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you indent your code correctly, you can easily see where the error is:

```
int CalculateResult(int High, int Low)
{
  int Result;
  int count = 0;
  int check;
  do
  {
     printf("Enter the value to check within the range: ");
     scanf("%d",&Result);

     if (Result == 0)
     {
         printf("Error! Positive value only!\n");
     }

     else if (Result < -1)
     {
         printf("Error! Positive value only!\n");
     }

     else if (Result >= 1);
     {
        for (check = Low ; check <= High; check++)
        {
           if (check%Result == 0)
           {
                 (count++);  <-------- The () are OK, but not necessary.
           }
        }
     }
  }  <---------------------------  Moved this brace up from below.
  while (Result != -1);

  return (count);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say addding no extra indent in an if-block is "correct", however.. a matter of taste

Comment: i reckon he is expecting to `return(count)` after the do-while loop is over. As per your Answer, it wont work.

Comment: @Nicklas This is Allman Style.  It has the virtue of allowing you to line up your opening and closing braces for comparison.  The OP appears to be using Whitesmiths style (more or less).

Comment: @TravisG: Then the code is worse than I thought, as you'd have to match the `while` to an opening `do`.

Comment: Well count wise his `{` and `}` are ok. only thing needed was just to move the second last `}` above the `while` and we all could be happy lads :)

Comment: @TravisG: Fixed (I think).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looks like so  :) . Over the years i use a a mental stack push-pull method( +1 to `{` and -1 to `}`) to quickly determine if the count is 0. Once zero is confirmed, the misplaced bracket can be easily identified.

Answer (score 1):

Add "}" before while instruction. You lost one bracket :) Now, "while" is for last "else if" instruction. Correct schema:

`do {

    //Some code here

} while (clause);`

Comment: SO MANY COMMMENTS lol thank you all. I fixed the code per all of your instructions, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
     } 
    while (Result != -1);
    return (count);
    }
}
```

to

```
     } 
     }
    while (Result != -1);
    return (count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only going to say two things:
1. Check if you have all the needed brackets
2. Check if you are missing a ";" or if there is a ";" where it shouldn't
This is a homework question so I won't give you the answer directly
Ok :), a few more tips:
1. Always indent your code
2. An `if` or `else if` without a block to do anything is probably a useless `if` or `else if` ;)